# Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator badges are not awarded when it takes more than 12 hours to approve an edit

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, badges

The Explainer, Refiner, and Illuminator badges descriptive text says:

> Edit and answer *[1/50/500]* questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer score > 0)

But this [does not appear to actually be true](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/15577).  It appears that the behavior is really based on when your edit is approved, not when the edit is made.  Is this a feature or a bug?

Comment: I'm guessing it's intentional, since the system can't award the badge until the edit is actually approved, as it may be declined and they don't revoke badges (generally). If it's any consolation when you get to 1K you won't have to wait for edits to be approved :D

Comment: @Catija, If this is so, then how to explain that the system will award progress towards the badge weeks later when the first upvote comes?

Comment: I don't know the technical side of it... my guess - the vast majority of those 50 edits and answers in 12 hours will be when users have edit permissions, so they ignore the "proposed" time stamp entirely because it is simpler and on most sites, suggested edits don't take 22 hours to be approved... so you're in a rare edge case due to  how long the review took. If I'm right, it's possible that they may consider adjusting it to look for a proposed time, wait for it to be accepted and go by that... but I'm guessing they'd want to see how many people are actually hurt by this.

Comment: @Catija once the edit is approved, it's possible for the badge award script to take the suggested edit time as the edit time. Not trivial to do, but also shouldn't be very complicated for skilled programmers. :-)

Comment: Was harder to find the dupe since you forgot to add the bronze badge name.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, There is no answer there?  Does this mean the dupe rules are different here?

Comment: The Button above asks me if the dupes reference solved my problem, but there is no answer, I guess that is another bug....

Comment: Yes, rules on Meta are different (not only here, any meta site) - there's no point leaving two same bug reports open. It's fine to have dupes, but not to leave them all open. There should be a clear trail to the original report/request. The "this solved my problem" can be read as "This was already reported before".

Comment: *Could be read as*.  I guess I could also read it as, *You will find true happiness*?  :-)  Kinda like a fortune cookie.  Random text which almost has some meaning...